# vs2012 creates false service feference in ServiceReferences.ClientConfig in xap

Tags: silverlight, visual-studio-2012, client, config, xap

I don't know if this is counted as a bug, but I am sure that is definitely wrong. I am working with three projects: two silverlight projects A and B, and a silverlight class library projet C. There are some common tasks that both A and B need to accomplish, so I put them into project C and both A and B reference to C. In project C a WCF servic is invoked. vs2012 creates for C a client config file to reference to WCF service. The key content of the config file is below:

```
<endpoint address="http://localhost:15154/StaffService.svc" 
          binding="..." bindingConfiguration="..." 
          contract="..."
          name="..." />
```

Please note that the address is absolute uri. At runtime the codes in C which invoke WCF service use in the fact the client config file of his invoinking application here named A and B. So I imitate what vs does for silverlight application and creat by hand in projects A and B client cofig file with relative uri like belows and delete the client config file in C.

```
<endpoint address="../StaffService.svc" 
          binding="..." bindingConfiguration="..." 
          contract="..."
          name="..." />
```

This relative uri means that service client classes in C are going to locate config from the parent folder of where A and B as xap is downloaded. So far everything is going all right till I publish the web site which holds A and B.

I am very satified with the performance of my projects in developing enviornment and a damper hited me in front of quite some VIPs right after I deployed them. The program does nothing. The screen is just a white paper.

After a whole day's digging, I found that the class libray C worked not. And the source of the problem is client config file in xap. Despite I have manually created config file with relative path, in the client config file in xap(how to see it: rename .xap to .zip and then open it as normal zip file), it was modified again into the abosolute uri like the first one:

```
    address="http://localhost:15154/StaffService.svc"
```

It certainly could not find any service at that address at runtime. I guessed what has tooken place: When I publish web site, vs recreates new client config files for each project which reference to WCF service and add this new created config file but not the one I manually created into xap.

Is there any remedial measures for tis problem?

I am feeling I am very unlucky that new problems emerged after I manually turned the uri back to right. The client browser loads always the old version of the application. I have tried to clear application cache using mage -cc, using Siverlight configuration tool at client, restarting IIS etc. All of them function not. I don't know if the following problems are related with I modifing the xap(I doesn't check Signing the xap file).

I must continue to struggle with them. God help me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue today. I am running VS2013 Update 2.

On the project I had configured my Publish Settings to use the Release Configuration, however, I always build using the Debug Solution Configuration. Set the Solution Configuration to match your Publish settings. Set to Release in my case. Build the project and Publish. The xap should now contain the correct ServiceReference.ClientConfig file.

You can change the Solution Configuration using the dropdown in the standard toolbar of VS or right-click on Solution in Solution Explorer select Properties -> Configuration Properties and use the Configuration dropdown at the top.

Hope this helps.